# "Текущие пенсионеры" — допустимо ли такое выражение публично?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> "Благодаря повышению пенсионного возраста, увеличатся страховые взносы, вследствие чего увеличатся пенсии текущим пенсионерам," ― объяснил чиновник в интервью с журналистом одного из центральных каналов ТВ.

Знал, что жизнь ― это река, но не знал, что пенсионеры текут.
Могу понять: "текущие пенсии", "текучесть кадров", "утечка мозгов"...  Но "текущие пенсионеры"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд, такое неприемлемо.

> [ТЕКУЩИЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9&all=x), -ая, -ее. 1. Происходящий, имеющий место теперь, в данное, настоящее время, теперешний. Т-ая действительность. Т. момент. Т. театральный сезон. // Относящийся к такому периоду, времени. Т-ие интересы. Т-ие планы. Т-ие новости. 2. Совершаемый каждый день, повседневный. Т-ее делопроизводство. Т-ая работа. Т-ие дела. Т. план (на ближайшее время). Т. ремонт (для устранения мелких неисправностей, обеспечивающий непрерывный и безаварийный рабочий процесс). Т. счёт (счёт вкладчика банка или сберкассы, с которого он может получать свои деньги по мере надобности и увеличивать его дополнительными вкладами).

Но почему планы и интересы могут быть текущими, а пенсионеры нет? Потому, что быть текущим, то есть происходить в данный момент или относиться к нему, может лишь то, что не являетя предметом, а человек и подавно не может быть текущим. Статус "пенсионер" — да, но не человек. Зарапортовался чиновник. А может, это оговорка по Фрейду? Для него все вокруг — пункты и дела.

Дополнение.

Нашлось в Нацкорпусе 4 вхождения (впрочем, авторов только два):

> Пенсионные накопления за 2014 год будут направлены в распределительную систему, то есть их используют для выплаты пенсий **текущим пенсионерам**. [Дина Ушакова. Выбор «молчуна» — отдать государству пенсионные накопления или нет? // Известия, 2013.10.01]
>
> То есть на выплату пенсий **текущим пенсионерам**. [Дина Ушакова. «Молчуны» лишатся пенсионных накоплений // Известия, 2013.09.18]
>
> На накопительную часть идет 6% от уплаченных работодателем за работника страховых отчислений в Пенсионный фонд России (общий тариф в ПФР составляет 22%, 16% идет на страховую часть пенсии, которая носит солидарный характер и направляется на выплаты **текущим пенсионерам**). [Дина Ушакова. Минтруда заставит пенсионные фонды перезаключать договоры с клиентами // Известия, 2013.07.11]
>
> По его словам, индексация никак не связана с реальными экономическими показателями, так как ориентируется исключительно на повышение уровня жизни **текущих пенсионеров**. [Татьяна Ширманова, Дина Ушакова. ВЭБ растерял треть пенсионных накоплений россиян // Известия, 2012.10.09]

Видно, далеко дело зашло...

Comment: Похоже, это стандартная рабочая фраза для чиновников. В ней отражено их отношение к простым людям.

Answer (score 1):

Это оговорка, и несложно понять её причины (я поясню ниже). Не думаю, что в ней можно найти что-то критично непубличное. Конечно, имелись в виду **теперешние**/**нынешние** пенсионеры.

Предполагаемые причины оговорки.
Чиновнику привычны выражения "текущий год/события/дела" и т. п. С другой стороны, слово "течь" может употребляться по отношению к людям: те же пенсионеры иногда "текут по улицам непрерывным потоком".

**Дополнение**.
Посмотрел поиском в сети. Выражение "текущие пенсионеры" употребляется, хотя и не очень часто. Более того, оно проникает в газеты, журналы и даже пару раз попалось в книгах. Мне оно не нравится, но я не исключаю, что в том канцелярите, в котором этих пенсионеров считают "штуками", оно приживётся.

Comment: Слова "теперешний и нынешний" имеют в словаре пометку разг.,  поэтому для канцелярского языка  не подходят. Что делать чиновнику, нет нужного термина. Взял словарь и нашел "походящую" замену: ТЕКУЩИЙ, -1. Происходящий, имеющий место теперь, в данное, настоящее время, ТЕПЕРЕШНИЙ.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо, интересное наблюдение. Я уверен, что много раз встречал в солидных изданиях выражение "нынешнее правительство" в официально-деловом стиле. Мне бы и в голову не пришло, что оно должно быть ограничено разговорным стилем. Что-то здесь не так.

Comment: А если написать так: ...вследствие чего увеличатся пенсии уже получившим свой статус пенсионерам.

Comment: Можно и так: ...увеличатся текущие пенсии.

Comment: Иногда можно, но все-таки не очень ясно.  А иногда речь идет именно о самих пенсионерах:  "ориентируются исключительно на повышение уровня жизни текущих пенсионеров".

Comment: Правительство-то не назовут текущим. Власть имущие слишком суеверны и бережно относятся к словам, к ним относящимся.

Comment: @Sharon По поводу разоворного статуса слова "нынешний". Это, очевидно, какое-то недоразумение или досадная ошибка. Я посмотрел работы лингвистов (Зализняк, Плунгян, Розенталь) — они свободно употребляют это слово в самых что ни на есть книжных стилях. Особенно часто это слово встречается в работах А. Зализняка.

Comment: Наверное, нет у этого слова подходящих синонимов, поэтому реальная стилевая характеристика может измениться. Но в словаре Ефремовой 2012 года есть пометка разг. И у наречия ныне тоже нет нейтрального значения (только высок. или разг.).  Поэтому и прилагательное кажется разговорным.  https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/315595.html